# How to hide and show element in Javascript/jQuery on keydown OR click?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mouseevent, keypress

I am trying to hide and show an input box with keydown event but I couldn't figure out how to do the same if clicked outside the input box.

HTML:

```
        <header>
        <h1>Hello {{visitorInput}}!</h1>
        <h4 id="greet">Nice to see you :)</h4>
        <form action="#">
            <input type="text" ng-model="visitorInput" id="visitorInput" placeholder="Please enter your name and press Enter.">
        </form>
    </header>
```

Javascript/jQuery:

```
var visitorInput = document.getElementById("visitorInput");

$('#visitorInput').focus();

    $('#visitorInput').keydown(function( event ){
        if(event.which == 13){
                $("#greet").show();
                console.log('Visitor name is: ' + visitorInput.value);
                //alert('Visitor name is: ' + visitorInput.value);
                $("#visitorInput").hide();
                    $('#greet, h1').click(function(){
                        $('#visitorInput').show().focus();
                        $('#greet').hide();
                    });
        };
    });
```

Comment: Use jQuery `.toggle()` instead. [***toggle***](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/)

Comment: You are using angular, then Why are you using jQuery to bind event

Comment: I am taking input from Angular and once user press Enter it saves the input value. I also want to save the input value if user clicks outside the input box.

Comment: Did you mean key down on the body ?

Comment: Anywhere outside the inputbox, but once the user click back on #greet, h1 the box should show up again.

Answer (score 0):

Use below coding

```
var visitorInput = document.getElementById("visitorInput");

$('#visitorInput').focus();

    $('#visitorInput').keydown(function( event ){
        if(event.which == 13){
                $("#greet").show();
                console.log('Visitor name is: ' + visitorInput.value);
                //alert('Visitor name is: ' + visitorInput.value);
                $("#visitorInput").hide();

        };

    });

$('#greet, h1').click(function(){
                            $('#visitorInput').show().focus();
                            $('#greet').hide();
      });
```

Apply the click event in outside of keydown event coding

Comment: This ain't working, keydown event is fine, I would like to hide the input if user click outside the input box

Comment: once the user click back on #greet, h1 the box should show up again

Comment: Yes but when the input box is displayed and user click outside the box then the input should hide

Comment: If user click anywhere, then hide input box, $(body).click(function(){
                            $('#visitorInput').hide();
                        
      });

Answer (score 0):

You stated in a comment that the keydown works as you want it to so I've only simplified the code there a bit and left the functionality alone, though it does seem like an odd UX to me so Im assuming there's more to it you dont show here.

Regarding making the input dissapear when the user clicks out of it, you want  [`.blur()`](https://api.jquery.com/blur/)

```js
var $visitorInput = $('#visitorInput').focus();
$visitorInput.keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.which == 13) {
    var $greet=$("#greet").show();
    console.log('Visitor name is: ' + visitorInput.value);
    $visitorInput.hide();
    $("#greet, h1").click(function() {
      $visitorInput.show().focus();
      $greet.hide();
    });
  };
}).blur(function(event) {
  $visitorInput.hide();
});
```

```css
#greet {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<header>
  <h1>Hello {{visitorInput}}!</h1>
  <h4 id="greet">Nice to see you :)</h4>
    <input type="text" ng-model="visitorInput" id="visitorInput" placeholder="Please enter your name and press Enter.">
</header>
```

Comment: This is also hiding the greet message

Comment: @Alrick Hiding it when?

Comment: When clicking out of the input

Comment: @Alrick I think I see what you mean. You want that when a user clicks the greet message or the any h1 tag, the input is shown again. Please see my edit

Comment: Exactly, but now I am getting this in console SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: You must have missed part of the code or created some other error when pasting, the code works in the snippet here